# KineticJS - Docs for previous version

Tags: kineticjs

Where can I find the Docs of a previous release of KineticJS. At http://kineticjs.com/docs/ there is only the doc of the current release.

Since the Kinetic API is changing fast I need to have a look at the older version 4.6.0

Answer (score 5):

Hope it can help you waiting a better answer :

https://web.archive.org/web/20130812021657/http://kineticjs.com/docs/index.html

4.6 release date of August 12, and this is exactly the date of the shot... but it seems to be the 4.5.5 doc... however, differences are few.

Answer (score 1):

KineticJS docs are dynamic and previous docs are not archived (yes, ouch!).

The best you can do is look at the change log to see what has changed after version 4.6.0

https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS/wiki/Change-Log