# Now that KineticJS is no longer maintained, where can I find its documentation?

Tags: kineticjs, konvajs

Active maintenance of [KineticJS](https://github.com/ericdrowell/KineticJS) was discontinued by its founder in [December 2014](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic.js). The documentation once hosted on the [kineticjs.com](http://kineticjs.com) website now [returns 404](http://kineticjs.com/docs/).

Where can I find the last version of the documentation?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two options:

#### 1. [Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20141205222238/http://kineticjs.com/docs/)

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23291301/1093087), you can use [web.archive.org](https://archive.org/web/) to find past archived versions. The latest archived version of the documentation dates back to [Dec 2014](https://web.archive.org/web/20141205222238/http://kineticjs.com/docs/).

#### 2. [Konva.js Documentation](http://konvajs.github.io/api/Konva.html)

This is my preference. [Konva.js](https://github.com/konvajs/konva) is an actively maintained fork of KineticJS. I find the documentation better organized and easier to use than the original documentation.

Since it is in active development, care must be given for possible changes in the API. Thus far, however, I have not encountered any discrepancies. While I await an opportunity to migrate over to Konva.js itself, this has been a great resource.

Answer (score 4):

Documentation
[Url for Docs](http://agavestorm.com/kineticjs/)

Tutorial [Url for Tutorial](http://www.zeali.net/mirrors/html5canvastutorials/kineticjs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-tutorial/index.html)

Comment: First link is dead

Comment: The second link is also dead